# "Fire and forget" T-SQL query in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, ssms

I have an Azure SQL Database where I sometimes want to execute ad-hoc SQL statements, that may take a long time to complete. For example to create an index, delete records from a huge table or copy data between tables. Due to the amounts of data involved, these operations can take anywhere from 5 minutes to several hours.

I noticed that if a SQL statement is executed in SSMS, then the entire transaction will be automatically rolled back, in case SSMS loses its connection to the server, before the execution is complete. This is problematic for very long running queries, for example in case of local wifi connectivity issues, or if I simply want to shut down my computer to leave the office.

Is there any way to instruct SQL Server or SSMS to execute a SQL statement without requiring an open connection? We cannot use SQL Server Agent jobs, as this an Azure SQL DB, and we would like to avoid solutions based on other Azure services, if possible, as this is just for simple Ad-hoc needs.

We tried the "Discard results after execution" option in SSMS, but this still keeps an open connection until the statement finishes executing:
[image]

It is not an asynchronous solution I am looking for, as I don't really care about the execution result (I can always check if the query is still running using for example `sys.dm_exec_requests`). So in other words, a simple "fire and forget" mechanism for T-SQL queries.

Comment: The problem with fire and forget is you're assuming success. Do you really want to fire and forget, discover 4 hours later that it's not done what you wanted but you've got no error message to inspect?

Comment: Talking about `fire-and-forget` has no meaning. When *any* connection closes, the transaction rolls back. The server doesn't care where that query came from.If you want a query to run in the background, schedule it to run as a job, or as part of an SSIS package. There are other mechanisms for this too

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - good point. Keeping in mind that this is an Azure SQL DB, what would, in your opinion, be the easiest way to run the query "from somewhere else" to support ad-hoc scenarios like I described?

Comment: @Dan Can't you split the work in batches which are committed individually?

Comment: @gotqn - well, for DML statements I probably could, but often times, I am applying DDL statements (adding/removing indexes, altering columns, etc.) which may take a long time to complete, and these cannot be split. A hiccup in my local wifi that happens when such a statement is in progress, is a major pain, as it can sometimes take even longer for the automatic rollback to finish.

Comment: You'll have to find a machine with a non-flaky connection. There's no way around that, since SQL Server will not hold open connections where the other side is gone. Ideally you'd do it on the machine itself (as in a scheduled job) but that's not an option for an Azure SQL DB, so the closest you can get is an Azure VM. Either do all work with RDP on such a remote machine, or invest in some Cat 5 cable.

Comment: Based on your requirements: No

Comment: @JeroenMostert - using an Azure VM with an RDP indeed seems to be the best option. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you are going to use an Azure VM (I thought you didn't want addiitonal components?) Then you might want to save yourself some cost and instead use `Azure Automation` to kick off scheduled SQL

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid - I'll look into that too. Indeed, it looks like there's no way around using other components to achieve this, so might as well go with the cheapest option.

Comment: Azure Automation is actually pretty handy. You can trigger a job from a URL (webhook) - that makes it pretty easy to trigger - no connectivity libraries required. You can trigger that from a single web page with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While my initial requirements stated that we didn't want to use other Azure services, I have found that using Azure Data Factory seems to be the most cost-efficient and simple way to solve the problem. Other solutions proposed here, seems to suffer from either high cost (spinning up VMs), or timeout limitations (Azure Functions, Azure Automation Runbooks), non of which apply to ADF when used for this purpose.

The idea is:

1. Put the long-running SQL statement into a Stored Procedure
2. Create a Data Factory pipeline with a Stored Procedure activity to execute the SP on the database. Make sure to set the Timeout and Retry values of the activity to sensible values.
3. Trigger the pipeline

Since no data movement is taking place in Data Factory, this solution is very cheap, and I have had queries running for 10+ hours using this approach, which worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you could put the ad-hoc query in a stored procedure you could then [schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job) to run on the server assuming you have the necessary privileges.

Note that this may not be a good idea, it but should work.

Comment: Downvoted as my scenario specifically does not allow me to use SQL Server Agent jobs (it's an Azure SQL Database - no SQL Server Agent available).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think you will be able to complete the query the without an open connection in SSMS.

I can suggest the following approaches:

1. Pass the query into an azure function / AWS Lambda to execute on your behalf (perhaps, expose it as a service via rest) and have it store or send the results somewhere accessible.
2. Start up a VM in the cloud and run the query from the VM via RDP.  Once you are ready you re-establish your RDP connection to the VM and you will be able to view the outcome of the query.
3. Use an Azure automation runbook to execute the query on a scheduled trigger.

Comment: Option 1 won't work for any query that takes more than ~10 minutes to run, as Azure functions time out before that. I don't know about AWS Lambda but I assume they have sort of the same limitation, being a serverless architecture after all. I'm trying to avoid the cost of having a VM running for the duration of the query, which rules out option 2. Automation runbooks (option 3) have a "fair use" limit, AFAIK, around 3 hours, so for queries running longer than this, I would face the same issue as option 1.